Meta rig is now no longer in character but rig is working fine?
I have a riggified character that I've been animating, and it's working fine but I just noticed the metarig for it is standing outside of it and does not move, I'm trying to understand how it got to be like this because I would now like to attach an object to the character but the metarig is no longer correctly associated with the character.
Thank you!


hello your metarig is no longer useful, now use the rig, note that by default the defromation bones are invisible but you can make them visible in the Data panel > Bone Collections

Your metarig is no longer useful, you can make invisible and use the rig instead. Note that by default the deformation bones are invisible but you can make them visible in the Data panel > Bone Collections:

As for attaching an object to the armature, there are several ways to do it, the most basic is to select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bone and CtrlP (Parent) > Bone.

Thank you! Can I attach an object to the rig?

You can attach an object to the new armature, what kind of object to what bone? If you are not familiar with armature it may be better to not use metarig kind of addons

Thank you! It worked perfectly.

to parent an object to a bone, select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bone and Ctrl P (Parent) > Bone, there are other ways, it really depends on the goal, for example if you want the character to be able to hold and drop an object, etc

Terrific! He is now holding a pencil.

But as I said,  if you want the character to be able to hold and drop an object you'll need to use another method, check the addon called Dynamic Parents
